# Get instance ID when running multiCapabilities in Protractor

Tags: angularjs, protractor

I'm using multiCapabilities with Protractor. Is there any way to get the instance ID that my tests is running on. I need this because I want each browser sign in with a different account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently it is not possible [per this GitHub ticket.](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/746)

What I did was using a buffer JSON file for keeping my configs per capability and use `fs` to read from it in `onPrepare` method that runs per capability. I mark each set of params that is used in the file again to avoid using the same set of params again. This way each capability can sign in with a different user name.

It was very manual but worked!

Answer (score 2):

What you want to look for is not "instance ID" but sessionID. You would retrieve this by running the following code in your spec:

```
browser.getSession().then(function(session) {
  // do something with sessionID.
});
```

This will provide the sessionID for the specific spec in a multiCapabilities configuration.